# Web API OData EnableLowerCamelCase

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API 2 application using OData and I need to expose the model properties in lower camel case as they are being serialized.

There is a [EnableLowerCamelCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn746676%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method that appears to do this but I can't get it to be recognized by the compiler. There is even a sample on CodePlex using OData 6.5.0 [that shows EnableLowerCamelCase](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataCamelCaseSample/ODataCamelCaseSample/ODataModels.cs).

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EnableLowerCamelCase(); // <-- this won't compile
```

Has EnableLowerCamelCase been removed? What am I missing?

I am using the following package versions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="elmah" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="elmah.corelibrary" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="6.8.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="6.8.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="6.8.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.5" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply change

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
```

to

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
```

or

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
```

and it should compile. I tested it using the latest ASP.NET Web API 2.2 for OData v4.0 (v5.3.1).